# How to stop new repo checkout in different Azure Stage?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm setting Azure pipeline into different stages like ExternalDependencies, InternalDependencies, UnitTesting, etc. I then realized in each stage, it performs repo checkout.

**The reason why I'm splitting them into multi-stages & jobs, because I can trigger to re-run failed jobs? Otherwise all the tasks are under 1 stage's step. When a part failed, I have to re-run the entire pipeline.

Screenshot below, you may spot the repo is checking out twice.

[image]

I suspect that this "new checkout" in the 2nd stage caused my Pod Installation failed.

```
stages:
- stage: ExternalDependencies
  jobs:
  - job: NPMInstallation
    steps:
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: "Perform NPM Installation"
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
        workingDir: './'

- stage: InternalDependencies
  jobs:
  - job: PodInstallation
    steps:
      - task: CocoaPods@0
        inputs:
          workingDirectory: 'ios'
          forceRepoUpdate: false
          projectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

How should I handle this scenario? My goal is to split the tasks into different jobs and stages, so I could see something like show in 2nd stages. Instead seeing only 1 stages is running.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add disable the checkout:

```
steps:
- checkout: none
```

See more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout).

Comment: Hi Shayki, thanks for responding. I have tried that, unfortunately that does not work. It seems that I have understand the concept of using Stages and Jobs incorrectly. Jobs seems to run in different agent, hence new checkout will always happened. If I were to put `- checkout: none` for the job, the job will have no source to build / perform the task.